# Cross validate results are negative

Tags: python

write a program, use cross validate to calculate the performance of support vector regression, the program is :

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('Dataset/allGlassStraightThroughTube.csv')
tube_par = dataset.iloc[:, 3:8].values
tube_eff = dataset.iloc[:, -1:].values
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_Y = StandardScaler()
sc_tube_par_X = sc_X.fit_transform(tube_par)
sc_tube_eff_Y = sc_Y.fit_transform(tube_eff)
scoring = ['neg_mean_squared_error', 'neg_mean_absolute_error']
rbf_svr_regressor = SVR(kernel='rbf')
scores = cross_validate(rbf_svr_regressor, sc_tube_par_X, sc_tube_eff_Y, cv=5, scoring=scoring,return_train_score=False)
print('scores')
print(scores)
```

it shows the result:

```
scores
{'fit_time': array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), 'score_time': array([0.        , 0.        , 0.01562428, 0.        
, 0.        ]), 'test_neg_mean_squared_error': array([-0.47939029, -1.46356871, -0.25270865, 
-0.43248573, -0.62049307]), 'test_neg_mean_absolute_error': array([-0.53858483, -0.78840699, 
-0.37781975, -0.44810543, -0.66178743])}
```

why the calculated mean_squared_error and the mean_absolute_error are all negtives and so big,
and it shows warning:

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:724: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
```

could you please tell me how to correct it

Answer (score 1):

The 'neg_mean_squared_error' and 'neg_mean_squared_error' will return a negated version of the score because internally sklearn always tries to maximize the metrics and in order to minimize the loss or the error, makes the metric negative and tries to maximizing it (as close as 0 as possible).

Comment: thank you ,but I found when use train_test_split to split the dataset as train data and test data(20%),use SVR to train and predict the test data(case 1), evaluation indexes such as R2,MSE,MAE are obtained, this is case 1; use cross_validate to split the dataset as 5 groups, train and test,   evaluation indexes such as R2,MSE,MAE are obtained, this is case 2; but the evalutions are so different between case 1 and case 2, for example, in case 1, MSE and MAE are little positive number, but in case 2, MAE and MSE are negative numbers, could you please tell me the reason and how to correct it

Comment: Is the dataset open? Do you have the data avalible? Maybe i can try it out and explain step by step

Comment: That is OK,could you please tell me your email, I send the program and the dataset to you, thank you

Comment: if you prefer, put it on github (public or private) and invite me to the repository (you can put your code also and then i will try it. My nick is anigmo97.Thanks

Comment: I have published mu problem on stackoverflow.com, the title is "python the evaluation index valus are different largely between cross validate and train_test_split cases", maybe You can read it and help me ,thank you

Comment: I will chek it out tomorrow, thaks. Try to leave a link to the data if it's possible.